# Show children (sub-navigation) of active menu item only

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

So I've searched the net and attempted to code a custom walker class that will do this, but I'm new to WordPress and although similar questions exist none fit exactly what I'm looking for, or suggest CSS, jQuery or a plugin as a solution (which is not really ideal).

I currently have the following code:

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';       

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';     

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<em>';
           $append = '</em>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
                     $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;            

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

      }
}
```

**What I'm trying to do is have it so that only the children (sub-menus) of the active navigation are shown, including all of the first level parent items.**

For example if you visit http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/home the "Download & Shop" link has no sub menu options, but once you navigate to that page, a sub-menu is present.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks

Comment: I am trying to understand your question.  Do you mean only when someone clicks on page three and thereby making it "active" is when you want to show the sub-menu for page 3 parent?

Comment: Yes, or if anyone were to view any sub-page of page 3 the submenu and parent would still need to be present. For example if you visit http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/home the "Download & Shop" link has no sub menu options, but once you navigate to that page, a sub-menu is present

Comment: Not sure how you mean but perhaps http://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-menu/

Comment: or http://wordpress.org/plugins/nice-navigation/

Comment: Thanks for the links but they don't really do what I'm looking for. I've edited my question so hopefully it's now clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok based on what I think you want from your description, you can accomplish this via CSS.  You don't need to create a custom walker for this unless you have other reasons to do so.

If you look carefully, when a menu item is active it will apply the following CSS to the "li" element

```
current-menu-item
current-menu-ancestor
```

So with that information, you can write your CSS rule to show/hide the sub-menus for that "li" item.

For example:

```
li > ul {
     display:none;
}

li.current-menu-item > ul, li.current-menu-ancestor > ul {
     display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with CSS. Follow the next steps:

1- Add this code into the tag BODY:

```
<?php body_class(); ?>
```

Like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

*This step will add a class to the current page. (It is usually used when we want to leave a button as marked when we are in its page).

2- Wordpress generates a dinamic code for the menus, which has its own classes. With this code we can access to the classes for the current page:

```
.menu li.current_page_item
.menu li.current-menu-item
```

3- So we can use something like this:

```
.menu li ul{opacity:0;visibility:hidden}
.menu li.current_page_item > ul, .menu li.current-menu-item > ul {display:block;opacity:1;visibility:visible}
```

Tested :)